# Visual Studio 2013 windows phone project templates doubts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have updated my code to WP 8.1 and wanted to organise it better by using Class Libraries.

The doubt comes when I find there are 2 Class library project templates for Windows Phone:

1. Class Library (Windows Phone)
2. Class Library (Windows Phone
   Silverlight)

If i select template 1, i see the assemblies referenced by default are .NET for Windows Store Apps and Windows Phone 8.1

If i select template 2, i got asked the target version of the Windows Phone OS (8.0 or 8.1) and the assemblies references by default are .NET for Windows Phone and Windows Phone.

Do you know the differences between them?
I have looked into the matter and seems it depends if you want to load the .NET runtime namespaces or not, am i correct? Are there any more differences?

Comment: First one is the WinRT apps where you can only develop apps for 8.1 platform if you're using VS 2013, and the second one is where you could choose the target version(ie: WP 8 or WP 8.1) for the Silverlight apps.

Comment: [Here you can find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn642486(v=vs.105).aspx) many differences between WP8.1 WinRT and Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class library type will depend on whether your main app will be a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, or Windows Phone 8.1 XAML app.

The advantage of WP8.1 XAML app is that it is converged with Windows 8.1 - you can even create an Universal App that shares almost all code and xaml between the Win8 and WP8.1 apps.

The advantage of WP8.1 Silverlight app is that it is more closer to the old WP8.0 app - less changes are required, and also it has access to some APIs not available to WP8.1 XAML apps.

Comment: Thats the kind of information I was looking for. Checked the MSDN but its pretty confusing with links pointing to the other choice documentation.